# How do I get the sum of a count and group by a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Getting stuck with a query getting the sum of counts.

I have a situation where I have to get every department and sum up all employee tasks

Currently my output is as follows

| Department | Total Tasks | Num Completed | Num Overdue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Asset Management | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Asset Management | 40 | 0 | 40 |
| Budget & Treasury | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Budget & Teasury | 13 | 8 | 6 |

Need this below output

| Department | Total Tasks | Num Completed | Num Overdue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Asset Management | 40 | 0 | 40 |
| Budge6 & Teasury | 14 | 8 | 7 |

```
DECLARE @DateFrom datetime = '2023-08-01'
DECLARE @DateTo datetime = '2023-09-27'

SELECT DISTINCT(u.Department),
    (SELECT COUNT(pt.to_resource) 
     FROM pcs_task pt WITH (nolock)  
     WHERE p.pcs_user_id = pt.to_resource 
       AND DATEADD(DAY, -30, @DateTo) > pt.date_closed 
       AND pt.due_date <= (@DateTo) 
       AND pt.date_alloc >= (@DateFrom) 
       AND date_closed <= @DateTo 
       AND pt.tsk_status = 'COMPLETE') +
    (SELECT COUNT(pt.to_resource) 
     FROM pcs_task pt WITH (nolock) 
     WHERE p.pcs_user_id = pt.to_resource 
       AND DATEADD(DAY, -60, @DateTo) >  pt.date_closed 
       AND pt.due_date <= (@DateTo) 
       AND pt.date_alloc >= (@DateFrom) 
       AND date_closed <= @DateTo 
       AND pt.tsk_status = 'COMPLETE') +
    (SELECT COUNT(pt.to_resource) 
     FROM pcs_task pt WITH (nolock) 
     WHERE p.pcs_user_id = pt.to_resource 
       AND DATEADD(DAY, 30, @DateTo) >= pt.date_alloc 
       AND pt.due_date <= (@DateTo) 
       AND pt.date_alloc >= (@DateFrom) 
       AND pt.tsk_status <> 'COMPLETE') + 
    (SELECT COUNT(pt.to_resource) 
     FROM pcs_task pt WITH (nolock) 
     WHERE p.pcs_user_id = pt.to_resource 
       AND DATEADD(DAY, 60, pt.due_date) >= pt.date_alloc 
       AND pt.due_date <= (@DateTo) 
       AND pt.date_alloc >= (@DateFrom) 
       AND pt.tsk_status <> 'COMPLETE') AS [Total Tasks],
    (SELECT COUNT(pt.to_resource) 
     FROM pcs_task pt WITH (nolock) 
     WHERE p.pcs_user_id = pt.to_resource 
       AND DATEADD(DAY, -30, @DateTo) > pt.date_closed 
       AND pt.due_date <= (@DateTo) 
       AND pt.date_alloc >= (@DateFrom) 
       AND date_closed <= @DateTo 
       AND pt.tsk_status = 'COMPLETE') +
    (SELECT COUNT(pt.to_resource) 
     FROM pcs_task pt WITH (nolock) 
     WHERE p.pcs_user_id = pt.to_resource 
       AND DATEADD(DAY, -60, @DateTo) > pt.date_closed 
       AND pt.due_date <= (@DateTo) 
       AND pt.date_alloc >= (@DateFrom) 
       AND date_closed <= @DateTo 
       AND pt.tsk_status = 'COMPLETE') AS [Num Completed],
    (SELECT COUNT(pt.to_resource) 
     FROM pcs_task pt WITH (nolock) 
     WHERE p.pcs_user_id = pt.to_resource 
       AND DATEADD(DAY, 30, @DateTo) >= pt.date_alloc 
       AND pt.due_date <= (@DateTo) 
       AND pt.date_alloc >= (@DateFrom) 
       AND pt.tsk_status <> 'COMPLETE') + 
    (SELECT COUNT(pt.to_resource) 
     FROM pcs_task pt WITH (nolock) 
     WHERE p.pcs_user_id = pt.to_resource 
       AND DATEADD(DAY, 60, pt.due_date) >= pt.date_alloc 
       AND pt.due_date <= (@DateTo) 
       AND pt.date_alloc >= (@DateFrom) 
       AND pt.tsk_status <> 'COMPLETE') AS [Num OVERDUE]
FROM         
    pcs_user p
INNER JOIN 
    Users u WITH (nolock) ON u.[Reference Number] = p.obj_id
WHERE     
    (p.user_status = 'Active') 
    AND p.pcs_user_id <> 'ADMIN'
    -- AND  (u.Department in (@Department))
ORDER BY 
    u.Department    --, p.pcs_user_id
```

I basically have to group all departments then get SUM of Total Tasks, Num COMPLETED and num OVERDUE for the users

WHEN I add SUM function on the count, I get this error:

> Sum function - cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Comment: Why do you use `NOLOCK` against *every* object in your `FROM`s apart from `pcs_user`?? If you "must" (you certainly don't) use it, then why are you not changing the isolation level of the transaction? [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: At least he's using `WITH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without example data, but the naive approach would be the following

```
WITH intermediate(department, total, completed, overdue) 
AS (SELECT ... )  --your current query as query for the CTE
SELECT department, SUM(total), SUM(completed), SUM(overdue)
FROM intermediate
GROUP BY department
```

Furthermore, the use of `DISTINCT` *may* indicate some problems with your data model or your query which leads to duplicate results. But again hard to say without seeing your model or example data ...

Comment: Thanks @derpirsher, worked like a charm

Comment: This certainly isn't the "best" way though, @DonaldDax . Looking at your query I suspect you just need some conditional aggregation, not a bunch of subqueries.

Comment: @ThomA No, it's certainly not the *best* way, that's why I called it the *naive* approach. But I honestly didn't want to work through that query, even less so when there is no datamodel or example data provided. So I gave a quick and dirty way to get the desired result from a query that's already working. Surely, with more input, one could provide a better query.

Comment: Quite obvious that OP is just using `DISTINCT` wrongly and just needs a normal `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2):

`DISTINCT` is not a function. It works on the whole resultset, so it's not grouping correctly.

The easiest way to group this kind of data is inside an `APPLY`. You can use conditional aggregation to avoid all those subqueries.

Also `nolock` is a bad idea, it has serious data integrity implications, and it's not a go-faster switch.

```sql
DECLARE @DateFrom datetime = '2023-08-01'
DECLARE @DateTo datetime = '2023-09-27'

SELECT
  u.Department,
  pt.*
FROM         
    pcs_user p
INNER JOIN 
    Users u ON u.[Reference Number] = p.obj_id
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
      COUNT(pt.to_resource) AS [Total Tasks],
      COUNT(CASE WHEN pt.tsk_status =  'COMPLETE' THEN 1 END) AS [Num Completed],
      COUNT(CASE WHEN pt.tsk_status <> 'COMPLETE' THEN 1 END) AS [Num OVERDUE]
    FROM pcs_task pt
    WHERE p.pcs_user_id = pt.to_resource 
      AND DATEADD(DAY, 30, @DateTo) >= pt.date_alloc 
      AND pt.due_date <= @DateTo
      AND pt.date_alloc >= @DateFrom
) pt
WHERE p.user_status = 'Active'
  AND p.pcs_user_id <> 'ADMIN'
-- AND u.Department in (@Department)  -- why use IN??
ORDER BY 
  u.Department    --, p.pcs_user_id
;
```

Alternatively just use a `GROUP BY` on the outside

```sql
DECLARE @DateFrom datetime = '2023-08-01'
DECLARE @DateTo datetime = '2023-09-27'

SELECT
  u.Department,
  COUNT(pt.to_resource) AS [Total Tasks],
  COUNT(CASE WHEN pt.tsk_status =  'COMPLETE' THEN 1 END) AS [Num Completed],
  COUNT(CASE WHEN pt.tsk_status <> 'COMPLETE' THEN 1 END) AS [Num OVERDUE]
FROM         
    pcs_user p
INNER JOIN 
    Users u ON u.[Reference Number] = p.obj_id
LEFT JOIN pcs_task pt
  ON p.pcs_user_id = pt.to_resource 
 AND DATEADD(DAY, 30, @DateTo) >= pt.date_alloc 
 AND pt.due_date <= @DateTo
 AND pt.date_alloc >= @DateFrom
WHERE p.user_status = 'Active'
  AND p.pcs_user_id <> 'ADMIN'
-- AND u.Department in (@Department)  -- why use IN??
GROUP BY
  u.Department
ORDER BY 
  u.Department    --, p.pcs_user_id
;
```